# Replace Specific Character and setText from getName specific Character

Tags: java, android, regex, android-studio

Please help me to solve this problem,

File Name : Beach Video @instagram.mp4

**My questions 1**
i want to get only "Beach Video" and remove "@"until the end word

**My questions 2**
i want to get only "@"until the end word and add a string "source" before "@"

- result questions 1 : Beach Video
- result questions 2 : Source    @instagram

> note : This is not just 1 file, there are many files with different
>   names. but the format is the same.

i try this but only delete last 10 character

Edit_Text(file.getName().replace(".mp4","").replaceFirst(".{10}$",""));

```
        videoUrl = picturePath  ;
        File file = new File(videoUrl);
        Log.v("SIZE",file.getName()+"");
        title.setText(file.getName());
        Edit_Text(file.getName().replace(".mp4","").replaceFirst(".{10}$",""));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple regex to parse your filename and capture the text you want into two groups and use them the way you want. This Java code should help. And the way this works is, the regex first captures everything before `@` (using `(.*)`) excluding any whitespace before that and second part is captured starting from `@` followed by one or more any character other than a dot using `(@[^.]+)`

```
String s = "Beach Video @instagram.mp4";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\s*(@[^.]+).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("First part: " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("Second part: Source " + m.group(2));
} else {
    System.out.println("Unexpected file format");
}
```

Prints both of your results the way you want,

```
First part: Beach Video 
Second part: Source @instagram
```

Can you check if this works well for you?

Comment: thank you for your answer, the first part work for me using "(@[^.]+)" but the second part can't work, "(.*)" this regex replace all string

Comment: are there any other suggestions?

Comment: @takoyaki: If you try and use my code, you will get both of your intended strings using one regex only. But I guess you are trying separately with two regex where `(@[^.]+)` will work but if you try using `(.*)` then it will match whole input and won't work alone and in that case you can use `[^@]+` to capture the text before `@` in your string.

Comment: [^@]+ it's only Show "@"

Comment: my code : setText(file.getName().replace(".mp4","").replaceAll("([^@]+)",""));

Comment: can you give me example with getName().matcher ?

Comment: @takoyaki: Hey, I've already given you the example with matcher in my post. What's your expected output? If you want to retain all text before `@` then use `^[^@]+` Check this demo https://regex101.com/r/WTsgj2/1/